# Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: line 183 pos 12: 'email != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Flutter to make a registration form using Firebase Authentication but this message keeps showing when I try to handle the authentication while trying to show the user the registration error message using the `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar SnackBar(content: Text(e.message)`at Sign-up widget

First I created an auth.dart file

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Auth {
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 //Sign up method
Future SignupClass(String email, String password) async {
final UserCredential user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
}
```

Then I created this TextField class to modularize my code

```
class Textfield extends StatelessWidget {
final String hint;
final IconData icon;
final Function savingData;
String _emptyMessage(String str) {
switch (hint) {
  case 'Enter your name':
    return 'Name is required';
  case 'Enter your e-mail':
    return 'Email is required';
  case 'Enter your Password':
    return 'Password is required';
}
}

Textfield(
  {@required this.savingData, @required this.hint, @required this.icon});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return _emptyMessage(hint);
      }
      return null;
    },
    onSaved: savingData
    }}
```

and This is the Sig-up widget

```
  class SignupScreen extends StatelessWidget {
static String id = '/SignupScreen';
GlobalKey<FormState> _globalKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
String _email, _password, _name;
final _auth = Auth();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(Textfield(
          hint: 'Enter your name',
          icon: Icons.person,
          savingData: (value) {
            _name = value;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: height * .02,
        ),
        Textfield(
          hint: 'Enter your e-mail',
          icon: Icons.email,
          savingData: (value) {
            _email =value;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: height * .02,
        ),
        Textfield(
          hint: 'Enter your Password',
          icon: Icons.lock,
          savingData: (value) {
            _password = value;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: height * .05,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 120.0),
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_globalKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    try {
                        await _auth.SignupClass(_email, _password);
                      _globalKey.currentState.save();
                    }on FirebaseException catch (e) {
                      print(e.toString());
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text(e.message),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                }),
          ),
        ),
     )
      }
```

```
and I wrapped my main function with  Firebase Initialize

    void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert your widget to a StatefulWidget and call setState() on your text fields' onChanged methods.  Because, the widget's state doesn't get updated until a build is called, your _email, _password and _name fields will never be updated. This will fix your issue, but there are better ways of doing this.

There are many state management libraries out there that greatly assist in keeping that kind of state outside the UI (Generally, it's better to separate any non-UI state from the UI). Here are a few recommendations:

1. BloC
2. Provider
3. RxDart

There are many tutorials on YouTube that you can check out.  A few I recommend are from AndyJulow, ResoCoder, and MarcusNg.

Comment: Great !! You helped me a lot ... Thanks so much @Scott